# Tool that allows pasting clipboard by iterating over contents and emulating key presses?

Tags: windows, clipboard

There are a few proprietary software suites that we use on a daily basis, where we're required to enter data manually into several form fields, which is fairly error prone. Simple clipboard pasting is not possible, probably due to the form fields listening to key press events, rather than being actual text fields.

We're looking for a tool that allows us to copy a piece of text, and then "special paste" it to the form fields. The special paste should then iterate over the clipboard contents, and emulate the corresponding key presses, so that we can get past the issue of pasting not working.

Are there any tools out there that implement this sort of behaviour?

Thanks in advance!